# Error response from daemon: Container is not running when running command from Docker image of openzim/zim-tools

Tags: windows, docker

I'm using Docker on Windows 10 for [openzim/zim-tools](https://hub.docker.com/r/openzim/zim-tools). Then I want to use the [command](https://openzim.org/wiki/Zimdump) `zimDump [options] zimfile`, i.e.,

```
zimDump -D "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\zim" "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\Documents\wiktionary_fr_all_maxi_2021-03.zim"
```

In command prompt, I type the following

```
docker ps -a
docker exec -it eager_nightingale zimDump -D "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\zim" "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\Documents\wiktionary_fr_all_maxi_2021-03.zim"
```

Then it returns the message

```
C:\Users\Akira>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
3f3fcdc4a238   openzim/zim-tools   "/bin/sh -c 'echo 'W…"   13 minutes ago   Exited (0) 13 minutes ago             eager_nightingale

C:\Users\Akira>docker exec -it eager_nightingale zimDump -D "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\zim" "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\Documents\wiktionary_fr_all_maxi_2021-03.zim"
Error response from daemon: Container 3f3fcdc4a2389be32f9dfbb0b1cf7a8d77e74aaef31555cd9724cae75dab7731 is not running
```

Could you please elaborate on where I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute the `zimDump` in a container that has stopped. You can see that the container is stopped from the status `Exited 0`. The reasons is that the container doesn't initiate a daemon as it's entry point, rather it only provide the tools, so better approach would be to use `run` with `--rm` to run instance of the container during the execution of the command, and to delete the container when the execution has finished. Depending on the nature of the commands executed, you might need to mount local folders as volumes to the image so the commands in the image have access to the files you want to process.

Comment: I've tried with `docker run -it --rm openzim/zim-tools:latest zimDump -D "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\zim" "C:\Users\Akira\Downloads\Documents\wiktionary_fr_all_maxi_2021-03.zim"`.

Comment: Then it returns an error `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "zimDump": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.`. Could you please elaborate on this one?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, you might need to mount the local folder as a volume in the container by using `-v`. Check for this specific image where you need to mount the folder

Comment: In the command I need to run, it will use the file `F:\zim\wikipedia_en_100_mini_2021-03.zim` and output html files to `F:\zim`. To do so, I tried `docker run -it -v type=bind,src=F:\\zim,dst=/app/config openzim/zim-tools:latest zimDump -D "F:\zim" "F:\zim\wikipedia_en_100_mini_2021-03.zim"`.

Comment: And it returns an error `If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.` :((